# angular forms json is unexpected, i.e. how to extract data from a form with minimal effort

Tags: javascript, json, forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working with a form in angular, and I have a directive I culled from working with another library that applies a function to a form:

```
app.directive('takesForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var form = angular.element(elem);
            form.bind('submit', function() {
                var button = form.find('button');
                button.prop('disabled', true);
                if(form.hasClass('ng-valid')) {
                    var args = arguments;
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope[attr.takesForm].apply(scope, args);
                    });
                } else {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope[attr.takesForm].apply(scope, [400, {error: 'Invalid form submitted.'}]);
                    });
                };
                button.prop('disabled', false);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

so all that is done is

```
<form takes-form="handleThisForm" name="itsaform">
     <input id="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="2345234value" name="csrf_token"</input>
     <input id="form_stuff" type="hidden" value="itvaries" ng-model="form_stuff" name="form_stuff"></input>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">do stuff with this form</button>
 </form>
```

which is all well and fine and works with A below:

```
function postStuff(formdata) {
        $http({method: 'POST',
               url: '/stuff/dot/url',
               data: formdata}).
            success(function(response){handleSuccess(response)}).
            error(function(response){handleError(response)})
    }

    $scope.handleThisForm = function(){
        // A. cumbersome, tear apart the form each and every time 
        update = JSON.stringify({'form_stuff': itsaform.form_stuff.value,
                                 'csrf_token': itsaform.csrf_token.value})
        postStuff(update)

        // B. just post the form
        //postStuff(update)
    };
```

The overall goal is to abstract the whole angular way and not have to do the redundant A every time for every form, i.e. do more with less repeated code in the future.

B. above results in a post something like:

```
"{
       "0": {},
       "1": {
           "ng-1402063246030": 50
       },
       "2": {},
       "3": {},
           "ng-1402063246030": 49
    }"
```

so I'm sort of lost reasoning through a limited js perspective & lack of familiarity of how best to do things in angularjs, whats the best way to streamline something like this?

edit:

I do not think the angular-ity of this is the question, I've reused something from a higher order library that wraps up some validation & preprocessing in an attempt to abstract useful reusable components, if it is wrong be more specific and also review the orginating repurposed directive code:

https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments/blob/master/lib/angular-payments.js#L726

which works....my question is about getting useful json that doesn't require manual construction every time the directive is used.

Comment: I don't quite get the concept of what all that code does, but one thing is for sure: it's not particularly "Angular-ish" at some points. E.g. you should probably use `ngSubmit` and the `$valid`/`$invalid` properties of the form's `FormController`.

Comment: the form element will map to the ngForm directive, creating a variable in the controller scope using the form name, you can perform several opertation on that form including checking its validity if you need to share a code among different forms you just need to create a form controller and assign it to eahc one of them using ng-controller. also  angular should take care of the csrf token handling for you you can read about both things https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm

Comment: The directive is extracted from angular-payments; which handles Stripe and does a lot, but I extracted what I thought relevant to be able to apply 1 function to a form.

Comment: There is nothing really about csrf specifically in the two links; I'm actually getting the csrf from elsewhere(its a wtforms form rendered through jinja2)